# How to convert ‘CollectionChain<string>' into 'ArrayLike<string | number>' in Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am using lodash.js version 4.17.15.
I have on 2D array as variable name dataArr,
I am going to perform following methos in chain to get count of each content of dataArr.
const countsObj = _.chain(dataArr).flatten().compact().countBy();

I have const count = 70,

Then I perform following method to get  content which are repeated by count times.
const keyMarker = _.chain(countsObj).invertBy().filter((value, key) => parseInt(key) == count).flatten();

as per documentation https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flatten , keyMarker shall be type Array.
If I print console.log(keyMarker), keyMarker is clearly shown as array with correct elements.
But _.isArray(keyMarker) is false and _.isObject(keyMarker) is true. keyMarker don’t have length size property. _.isArray(keyMarker) is showing 5 irrespective of numbers of elements in array. If I do slice like keyMarker[0], I am getting undefined.

When ever try to get intersection of  keyMarker with other array, it is showing following error,
“Argument of type 'CollectionChain' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayLike<string | number>'.
Property 'length' is missing in type 'CollectionChain' but required in type 'ArrayLike<string | number>'.”

I am new to Lodash, can anyone advise me how to convert CollectionChain generated by Lodash to 'ArrayLike<string | number>'?

Thanks
Shailesh Patel

Comment: Can you add the original arr? a working snippet, or at least a block of code would be great.

Comment: Thanks @OriDrori
 , I have created snippet in codepen here [link](https://codepen.io/techindia2010/pen/QWrZdRg). 
You can see that dataArr is 2D array. It is type as array. I used chain wrapper and do flattenDeep, as per documentation it should return Array, but it return object, and dataArr is value of key “__wrapped__” , without flattened. 
My actual application is on Script Lab hosted on Microsoft Excel. Current behavior is different than on script lab. If you are familiar of Script Lab, I will share gist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash sequences are lazily evaluated. To resolve the chain, and get the result from  from the chain's object, you need to use `.value()`:

```js
const dataArr = [["","","","","","","","","",""],["","INVOICE","","","","","","","",""],["","","","","","","","","",""],["","","","","","","INVOICE # 1","","",""],["","","","","","","","","",""],["","","","","","","","","",""],["","","","","","","DATE","","",""],["","","","","","","","","",""],["","From:","","","","","To:","","",""],["","Your name","","","","","Receivers Name","","",""],["","Address","","","","","Address","","",""],["","Email Address","","","","","Email Address","","",""],["","Phone number","","","","","Phone number","","",""],["","","","","","","","","",""],["","","","","","","","","",""],["","#","Item name","","","Qty","Unit cost","Discount","Total",""],["",1,"Do It Yourself Tornado Kit","","",1,"$489.00 ","","$489.00 ",""],["","Signature","","","","","","","",""],["","","","","","","","","",""],["","","","","","","","","",""],["","Your company name, address and footer","","","","","","","",""]];

const countsObj = _(dataArr)
  .flattenDeep() // flattens multi-dimensional array
  .compact() // removes empty values
  .countBy() // creates an object of [value]: times
  .value(); // executes the chain sequence to resolve the unwrapped value

const count = 2;

const keyMarker = _(countsObj)
  .pickBy(v => v === count) // take properties by condition
  .value(); // executes the chain sequence to resolve the unwrapped value

console.log('countsObj\n', countsObj);
console.log('keyMarker\n', keyMarker);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```